# random error with Ruby string

Tags: ruby

So, I've been learning Ruby on Codecademy. And I've had to repeat the first code snippet for an error that I'm completely confused about. Here is what I'm typing.

```
my_num = 25

my_boolean = true

my_string = “Ruby”
```

And yet when I submit this code to codecademy it keeps complaining that my string isn't properly done.

```
undefined local variable or method `“Ruby”' for #<Context:0xc161dc>
```

Can anyone tell me if they see anything wrong with this? As far as I know I'm following all the language's rules.

Comment: Your quotes are strange. Try `"Ruby"` instead of `“Ruby”`.

Comment: @ndn: True, I didn't see that.

Comment: @JorgePaez: Some texteditors (e.g. TextEdit) try to be clever and convert `"` to `“`.

Comment: Mac curly quotes can be disabled globally: http://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks

Comment: In this case, single quotes like ' work

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your string is formatted with wrong delimiters. The quotes must be `"` instead of your `“` and `”`.

Try with the following instead:

```
my_string = "Ruby"
```

Comment: You can also as a convention use single quotes `my_string = 'Ruby'` unless you're passing variables.